# Generalized integral based on ${e}^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was thinking about the integral of ${e}^{-x^2}$(which is erf(x)$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ + C) and the erf error function and making things more generalized. I got an idea to try not just ${e}^{-x^2}$ but ${n}^{-x^a}$. I was definitely expecting something with the error function, because it was used when n = e and a = 2. So I put it into W|A, expecting to be able to prove the answer it outputted with little hardship.

But I got something *entirely* different. And I couldn't prove it at *all*, so here I am. The answer was:

$$-\frac{x({{x}^{a} \log(n))}^{\frac{-1}{a}} Γ(\frac{1}{a}, {x}^{a} \log(n))}{a} + C$$

I was so surprised! I'm sorry that I can't give my own attempts, but I have no idea how to approach the question, which is to *prove* the answer is

$$-\frac{x({{x}^{a} \log(n))}^{\frac{-1}{a}} Γ(\frac{1}{a}, {x}^{a} \log(n))}{a} + C$$

So try to prove the answer . Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This is, effectively, the definition of the [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution to make is rather simple. First of all, write it into the exponential form:

$$n^{-x^a} = e^{-x^a \ln(n)} = e^{x^a \ln(1/n)}$$

Now make the substitution

$$z = x^a\ln(1/n) ~~~~~~~~~~~ x = \sqrt[a]{\dfrac{z}{\ln(1/n)}}$$

$$\text{d}z =a x^{a-1}\ln(1/n) \equiv \beta\frac{z}{z^{1/a}} \text{d}x$$

Where $\beta = \text{constant} = a\ln(1/n)\sqrt[a]{\ln(1/n)}$

Hence the integral becomes:

$$\large \frac{1}{\beta}\int e^z z^{1/a\ - 1} \text{d}z$$

And now it's all about Gamma Function, complete and incomplete.

You can find the most general treatment of the Complete and Incomplete Gamma Function on whatever textbook of Analysis 1 or Special Functions!